# Error al gestionar un JSON: Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, datatables

Buenas tengo un JSON que cojo de la pubg api y lo he transformado para lo que necesito, el json es el siguiente:

```
{
    "data": [{
        "nombre": "Nomemate",
        "atributo": {
            "assists": 287,
            "bestRankPoint": 4314.65,
            "boosts": 1037,
            "dBNOs": 708,
            "dailyKills": 19,
            "dailyWins": 1,
            "damageDealt": 119668.64,
            "days": 63,
            "headshotKills": 167,
            "heals": 1303,
            "killPoints": 0,
            "kills": 751,
            "longestKill": 453.62796,
            "longestTimeSurvived": 1954.96,
            "losses": 523,
            "maxKillStreaks": 4,
            "mostSurvivalTime": 1954.96,
            "rankPoints": 4314.65,
            "rankPointsTitle": "5-4",
            "revives": 195,
            "rideDistance": 708221.06,
            "roadKills": 0,
            "roundMostKills": 7,
            "roundsPlayed": 573,
            "suicides": 7,
            "swimDistance": 4756.804,
            "teamKills": 10,
            "timeSurvived": 494004.94,
            "top10s": 265,
            "vehicleDestroys": 14,
            "walkDistance": 806560.6,
            "weaponsAcquired": 2594,
            "weeklyKills": 67,
            "weeklyWins": 4,
            "winPoints": 0,
            "wins": 57
        }
    }, {
        "nombre": "KeTeMeTo",
        "atributo": {
            "assists": 56,
            "bestRankPoint": 2828.7388,
            "boosts": 336,
            "dBNOs": 114,
            "dailyKills": 1,
            "dailyWins": 0,
            "damageDealt": 19943.97,
            "days": 34,
            "headshotKills": 41,
            "heals": 436,
            "killPoints": 0,
            "kills": 139,
            "longestKill": 324.68155,
            "longestTimeSurvived": 1899.685,
            "losses": 161,
            "maxKillStreaks": 2,
            "mostSurvivalTime": 1899.685,
            "rankPoints": 2828.7388,
            "rankPointsTitle": "3-1",
            "revives": 59,
            "rideDistance": 288549.62,
            "roadKills": 0,
            "roundMostKills": 5,
            "roundsPlayed": 165,
            "suicides": 4,
            "swimDistance": 1124.9402,
            "teamKills": 4,
            "timeSurvived": 159221.55,
            "top10s": 78,
            "vehicleDestroys": 4,
            "walkDistance": 282959.44,
            "weaponsAcquired": 710,
            "weeklyKills": 1,
            "weeklyWins": 0,
            "winPoints": 0,
            "wins": 8
        }
    }]
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#rank').DataTable( {
        ajax: {
            url: 'table/datos.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            columns :[
                {data: 'nombre'},
                {data: 'atributo.assists'},
                {data: 'atributo.bestRankPoint'},
                {data: 'atributo.boosts'},
                {data: 'atributo.dBNOs'},
                {data: 'atributo.dailyKills'},
                {data: 'atributo.dailyWins'},
                {data: 'atributo.damageDealt'},
                {data: 'atributo.days'},
                {data: 'atributo.headshotKills'},
                {data: 'atributo.heals'},
                {data: 'atributo.killPoints'},
                {data: 'atributo.kills'},
                {data: 'atributo.longesstKill'},
                {data: 'atributo.longestTimeSurvived'},
                {data: 'atributo.losses'},
                {data: 'atributo.maxKillStreaks'},
                {data: 'atributo.mostSurvivalTime'},
                {data: 'atributo.rankPoints'},
                {data: 'atributo.rankPointsTitle'},
                {data: 'atributo.revives'},
                {data: 'atributo.rideDistance'},
                {data: 'atributo.roadKills'},
                {data: 'atributo.roundMostKills'},
                {data: 'atributo.roundsPlayed'},
                {data: 'atributo.suicides'},
                {data: 'atributo.swimDistance'},
                {data: 'atributo.teamKills'},
                {data: 'atributo.timeSurvided'},
                {data: 'atributo.top10s'},
                {data: 'atributo.vehicleDestroys'},
                {data: 'atributo.walkDistance'},
                {data: 'atributo.weaponsAcquired'},
                {data: 'atributo.weeklyKills'},
                {data: 'atributo.weeklyWins'},
                {data: 'atributo.winPoints'},
                {data: 'atributo.wins'},
            ]
        },
    } );



} );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<table id="rank" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Asistencias</th>
        <th>BestRankPoint</th>
        <th>Boost</th>
        <th>dBNOs</th>
        <th>dailyKills</th>
        <th>damageDealt</th>
        <th>days</th>
        <th>headshotKills</th>
        <th>heals</th>
        <th>killPoints</th>
        <th>kills</th>
        <th>longestKill</th>
        <th>longestTimeSurvived</th>
        <th>losses</th>
        <th>maxKillStreaks</th>
        <th>mostSurvivalTime</th>
        <th>rankPoints</th>
        <th>rankPointsTitle</th>
        <th>revives</th>
        <th>rideDistance</th>
        <th>roadKills</th>
        <th>roundMostKills</th>
        <th>roundsPlayed</th>
        <th>suicides</th>
        <th>swimDistance</th>
        <th>teamKills</th>
        <th>timeSurvived</th>
        <th>top10s</th>
        <th>vehicleDestroys</th>
        <th>walkDistance</th>
        <th>weaponsAcquired</th>
        <th>weeklyKills</th>
        <th>weeklyWins</th>
        <th>winPoints</th>
        <th>wins</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

este es el error 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el caso es que quiero que me muestre un listado con los usuarios y estos resultados, y me da error, Cuando consiga que los datos se muestren correctamente también querría hacer algunos cálculos antes de mostrar los datos, esto seria posible también?

Comment: Sin saber el error que te da, es imposible ayudarte. ¿Qué problema tienes?

Comment: el error es en como lee los datos, porque datatables sabe que hay dos registros, pero no sabe como manipularlos, casi seguro porque el {data: "xxxx"} lo tengo mal puesto, pero lo he revisado varias veces y no encuentro el fallo

Comment: @PabloLozano sigo con el mismo error, y no encuentro el porque, estoy mirando por google y he puesto todo lo que dice, y sigue igual

Comment: si el error me lo da cuando intento pintar los valores, la peticion la hace bien de echo para las pruebas he metido el json en una variable, el json que recibo parece que tiene el formato correcto, pero cuando intento acceder a los datos mediante datatables con columns:[ { data: 'atributo.assists } ] por ejemplo no pinta nada y da el error ese que es como si fuese null, por lo que sospecho que asi no se accede a los datos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error es que has definido la propiedad `columns` dentro de la propiedad `ajax`.

### Solución:

Debe mover `columns` al mismo nivel que `ajax` (no dentro).

#### Ejemplo:

```
$('#rank').DataTable( {
  ajax: {
    url: 'table/datos.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json'
  },
  columns :[
    {data: 'nombre'},
    //...
```

Comment: titan...... madre mia 1 hora o mas mirando otros que tengo hechos y funcionaban y no me di cuenta de eso! muchas gracias!

Comment: @KeTeMeTo, a todos nos ha pasado mas de una vez ;)